# Oracle Elapsed time vs CPU time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have oracle AWR report and i see two terms mentioned there  against each sql statement but i am not clear what is the difference b/w them
i read couple of articles  but still i am able to grasp the concept

Say my get the report of oracle server between 1pm to 1.10 pm i.e for 600 seconds. Assume there are two cpu and they are running full time, i believe it means total cpu time
for all java processes on DB server is 1200 seconds. Right ?

Now say i have a query  say `select * from employee where id =1` which displays elapsed time as 10 sec and CPU time as 4 sec. Now my question i believe CPU time(4 sec) 
is the actual time to execute the query and fetching result. But why elapsed time is 10 seconds then ?

Does elapsed time is equal to Elapsed Time  = CPU time + wait time(Non Idle wait time) ?

Comment: I think this should provide you answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568855/what-causes-the-difference-between-cpu-time-and-elapsed-time-in-oracle-tkprof-fi?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If the elapse time for the query is 10 and CPU time is 4 then the query took 4 seconds to execute on CPU and rest of the time(6 seconds) spent on non-idle wait.

For demonstration look at the following screen shot of Oracle Enterprise Manager query statistic page.

[image]

Where `Elasped Time(sec)=250.31` which is futher divided into CPU Time and Wait Time.

[image]

Same as above the `35.7%` of time was spent on CPU and rest of it on waits(User I/O).

So `Elapsed Time=CPU Time + Wait Time(I/O, Network etc.)`.